# Entity Framework Decimal Inconsistency

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I'm implementing the tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller

I use Entity Framework 4.1. In the database decimal value is mapped (18,2).
In the creating form I entered 1000 but in the details page the decimal value output is 1000,00 and also in the edit page as well.
I use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)` for input and for output.
When I looked at the database created by the Entity Framework the Price column which is my decimal value is created with this SQL command:

```
[Price] DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL
```

Why there is inconsistance?

Comment: I entered 1000 as input but output is 1000,00
Why it doesn't show 1000 and table is created with Decimal(18,2)

Comment: Because 1000,00 is the 1000 with two decimal places (ie:the 2 in decimal 18,2)

Comment: I added this code in DbContext:
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>().Property(p =>p.Price).HasPrecision(18, 0);
}
decimal column in databse is now (18,0) but still the output is 1000,00 should I format the decimal in the POCO? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two different things. The mapping describes the precision which can be stored in the database but it has nothing to do with the way how your ASP.NET MVC View shows decimal number - it is handled by output formatting.